# How to store form data In temporarily react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a registration form, I'm filling some form elements. Meanwhile if I click term and condition link. It'll redirect to that page. After come back same register page, there is all fields are empty. Again I start to fill up form from scratch.

So I need whatever I fill up as auto fill in form elements. That means my state values updated. How to possible in React JS?

Comment: did you check localStorage????

Comment: check react-cookie

Comment: Is there any way to do in component life cycle or redux!

Comment: could you show your code

Comment: yes you can do in redux if r using it.Redux store always the hold app data and it will only lost when you do page refresh considering no restoration from  localStorage

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple approaches to this problem.

1. Pass data to the new navigated page, and on completion of the action, you can pass back data to the registration form and have your form populated.
2. Store all data in a state, and update state on each form input entry. So, once all entries are made your state is updated with all values. The only constraint here is that, the DOM node shouldn't go out of scope or shouldn't disappear from the DOM tree.
3. Use redux to store all form values

Answer (score 1):

I myself am not familiar with React, but [this](https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f) seems like a great tutorial on how to handle form in the ReactJS. His form seems to remember the previous input even after reload, also he generates the form dynamically, and he provides nice JSFiddle code on `Fiddle code:`[this](https://jsfiddle.net/everdimension/5ry2wdaa/) link.
Hope this has what you are looking for.